# TeX.SE editor: insert citation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, community, user-interface

In the site Math.SE. I have seen that there is also an icon (marked with an orange square in the image below) named "insert citation".

[image]

In TeX.SE this icon doesn't exist.

[image]

Is it important to have this icon also in TeX.SE, for a citation (`cite`, `BibLaTeX`, etc) or something else?

Comment: I don't think so. Most answers at best quote from package documentation, which is best inserted via a link if at all. There is very little published work on TeX itself apart from the TeXbook and the PracTeX journal. And this functionality has nothing to do with TeX bibliography packages.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you very much for your reply. If there are the news...I am here. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. Most answers at best quote from package documentation, which is best inserted via a link if at all. There is very little published work on TeX itself apart from the TeXbook and the PracTeX journal. And this functionality has nothing to do with TeX bibliography packages. You can insert a link by clicking on the circled icon in the image below.

If you do link to package documentation I would recommend using a link via [`texdoc.net`](https://texdoc.net). But in most cases I don't think links to documentation are really necessary.

[image: edit window image]

Comment: Very kind Alan, please, can you do an example with the screenshot, just to understand very well your answer. I understand better the question and the answer with the images. Now I check mark your answer.